# Too much whitespace?

Tags: website-design, white-space

I do know that *whitespaces* play a crucial role in design.

But while doing my design, specially for larger screens (like Desktop), I feel like there is **too much whitespace** in my design.

Is it just me or it's a common thought ?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your designs? While it is true that screen sizes are becoming bigger all the time and the screen resolutions are better than ever, the use of responsive web design strategies should help address some of these issues.

Comment: I am not really sure what the question is here. An opinion on whether a design has too much whitespace of not is very dependant on your specific design and data, not really something than we can give a general answer to. Take this very site for example, there is a lot of whitespace (is your screen is big enough), but it works because of the type of content.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. You can absolutely have too much white space. Some examples:

- Your paragraphs are uncomfortably narrow because the margins are too wide, which makes the reader have to keep [jumping to the next line](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability).
- Your page becomes overly long and the user has to keep scrolling. Items that could fit comfortably together are no longer on the same screen, which could annoy the user.
- You users might [prefer higher data density](https://uxdesign.cc/how-white-space-killed-an-enterprise-app-and-why-data-density-matters-b3afad6a5f2a) in order to complete their tasks, and the white space in your tables is getting in the way.

If you are unsure about how much white space is too much, read more about [using grid-based layouts](https://visme.co/blog/layout-design/).

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Comment: This answer is a little confusing as your first point is more in favour of white space than it is against it. In that paragraph width should be limited regardless of how much space there is available, which will result in much more whitespace on larger screens (for example, how this site is designed).

Comment: Paragraph width absolutely should be limited, but it's possible to make paragraphs *too* narrow. Good designers will usually use multiple column layouts on big screens to fill space vs. making paragraphs span 960 pixels.